# Add a gap to individual signal with tikz-timing

Tags: tikz-timing, timing-diagrams

I want to produce timing diagrams using `tikz-timing`.

Using `wavedrom` there is a possibility to add gaps to individual signals.

[image]

There is an option to do so with `tikz-timing` as well?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I guess you want to provide us with what you've already tried. As it stands now, if people were mean they would just answer with "Yes", which is as specific as the current version of this question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The short answer is that, yes, this is possible do *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please draw this for me" that show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A quick search on TeX.SX for drawing functions (with tikz or pstricks) will give you an idea of where to start from.