# How do I make a time gap in LaTeX using tikz-timing?

Tags: tikz-timing, timing-diagrams

Is there a way to make a timing gap using the tikz-timing package or tikz, like the timing gap highlighted in the picture below?

[image: Timing Gap]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide us with an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), not just a screen shot.

Comment: Just one more thing: an almost identical question (I believe) has been asked [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/419188/121799), also without MWE. As you see, there is no answer. So, if you want to have a timely answer (and also avoid that your question is being closed), please consider posting an MWE.

Comment: Yes there is a reference to an web api, with online editor to make this [wavedrom](https://wavedrom.com/editor.html), its an open source HTML5 and has the option implemented for gaps, for the [tikz-timing](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-timing/tikz-timing.pdf), in a quick view I did not find something similar, only dotted separations. Maybe, if you provide the precious and required MWE, some experts can do it using their best tricks in the tikz way ...

Answer (score 4):

(Because I was a bit bored:) Note, there are bound to be several other ways of doing the same thing, and likely better ways. I define a style for a node, and draw the gap symbol as a `path picture`. The placement will depend on your diagram. In this case note the timing specification (`2L N(A1)  4H N(A2) L`) includes two named nodes `A1` and `A2`, and the `gap` node is placed using those as a reference.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
  alias path picture bounding box/.code=%https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/395628
    \pgfnodealias{#1}{path picture bounding box},
  gap/.style={
    circle,
    inner sep=0pt,
    minimum size=#1,
    node contents={},
    path picture={
       \tikzset{alias path picture bounding box=@}
       \fill [white] (@.265) to[out=40,in=220] (@.70) -- 
                     (@.85)  to[out=220,in=40] (@.250) -- cycle;
       \draw [very thin] (@.265) to[out=40,in=220] (@.70)
                         (@.85)  to[out=220,in=40] (@.250);
    }
  },
  gap/.default=10pt
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikztimingtable}
    foo & 2L N(A1)  4H N(A2) L\\
    \extracode
    \node[gap, at={($(A1|-A2)!0.5!(A2)$)}];
\end{tikztimingtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What does `($(A1|-A2)!0.5!(A2)$)` mean?

Comment: @Michael `($(a)!0.5!(b)$)` is the point halfway between `a` and `b`, and `(a|-b)` is the point that has the x-coordinate of `a` and the y-coordinate of `b` (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/401425).

Comment: If I want to draw a gap at A1 I just need to use $A1$?

Comment: @Michael No, the dollar signs are for coordinate calculations, use just `at={(A1)}`

Comment: Thank you. It is strange that there is no a standard way to insert a gap.